# What's the word for something scary but actually harmless?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a noun (or noun phrase) for ***something scary but actually harmless***?

I've thought of "bugbear" but it's not very accurate.

An adjective somewhat the opposite of *insidious* (as in "deadly while appearing to be harmless") would be welcome too.

Comment: [A word/phrase for something that is outwardly fearsome, but in reality is nothing to worry about](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120549/a-word-phrase-for-something-that-is-outwardly-fearsome-but-in-reality-is-nothin)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not a single word, but the term *paper tiger* is used this way, though it also has political connotations due to its origin in Maoist era anti-US propaganda and its continued usage in political contexts.

The meaning isn't an exact match either, since it means "threatening but harmless", rather than "scary" in the horror-movie sense.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paper%20tiger):

> : one that is outwardly powerful or dangerous but inwardly weak or ineffectual
>   //  The new laws are just *paper tigers* without any method of enforcement.

Comment: Actually, this fits my use perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a link to and quotation of a definition of the term. (Generally, when providing an answer like this, it's a good idea to cite something authoritative.) Feel free to make any changes to what I've done.

Answer (score 1):

Very close to "bugbear" is ***[bugaboo](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bugaboo)***:

> 1: an imaginary object of fear
>
> // politicians complaining about that old *bugaboo*, high oil prices
> // doing one's tax returns are a real *bugaboo* for some people
> <sub>*definition from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bugaboo)*</sub>

from Oxford Dictionaries:

> An object of fear or alarm; a bogey.
> // ‘one of the favourite *bugaboos*, the ticking biological clock’
> <sub>*definition from [oxforddictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bugaboo)*</sub>

Note that despite the definition as "imaginary", the quoted usages are about real items that cause undue fear.

Comment: That comes close, but it has other meanings that make it unsuitable as they suggest that the object is a real thing that can cause real harm, e.g. "A recurring or persistent problem" or "a source of concern" from other dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking perhaps of phobias? Phobias are only “scary” to those suffering with the actual phobia, or irrational fear— but it’s often the case that most people would not find said phobia to be alarming or disconcerting (if they aren’t suffering also with the phobia, that is)

Comment: No, not _phobia_. But thanks for trying. And welcome!